# Extend Highchart to edges of container

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a Highcharts area chart with no labels that I'd like to take up the entire size of its container (i.e. with the chart itself up to the very edge). I have already disabled the labels on each axis and set `reserveSpace` to `false` and `padding` to `0`, yet my chart still does not expand to the very edges (see below screenshot):

[image]

I have this in my chart config:

```
...,
xAxis: {
  ...,
  title: {
    enabled: false,
    reserveSpace: false
  },
  labels: {
    enabled: false,
    reserveSpace: false,
    padding: 0
  },
  tickLength: 0,
  lineWidth: 0,
  tickWidth: 0,
  ...
},
yAxis: {
  ...,
  gridLineWidth: 0,
  minorGridLineWidth: 0,
  title: {
    enabled: false,
    reserveSpace: false
  },
  labels: {
    enabled: false,
    reserveSpace: false,
    padding: 0
  },
  tickLength: 0,
  minPadding: 0,
  maxPadding: 0,
  ...
},
...
```

How can I accomplish extending the lines out to the very edge of its container?

Comment: Have a look at https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.spacing

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for! Can't believe I didn't spot that while spending hours searching through their documentation. Please post this as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`chart.spacing`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.spacing) is the option you are looking for.

> spacing: Array.Since 3.0.6
>   The distance between the outer edge of the chart and the content, like title or legend, or axis title and labels if present. The numbers in the array designate top, right, bottom and left respectively. Use the options spacingTop, spacingRight, spacingBottom and spacingLeft options for shorthand setting of one option.
>
> Defaults to [10, 10, 15, 10].